# Tensorflow implementation for bank transaction classification

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

I am building a simple machine learning model that takes bank transactions as input (see features below) and I want to predict the spend category (label). I have already worked through some beginner's tutorials, such as [ML Crash Course](https://developers.google.com/machine-learning/crash-course/), [Text Classification Guides](https://developers.google.com/machine-learning/guides/text-classification/step-2-5), [Word Embeddings](https://www.tensorflow.org/beta/tutorials/text/word_embeddings), and more.

Here is exemplary input data:

```
Date;Sender / Recipient;IBAN / Account#;BIC / Bank Code;Text;Amount;Category
02.07.2019;Tesco Market;HSVSDDMM;Grocery Market London Heathrow - Thank you for purchase;-48.06;Groceries
```

My goal is to predict the `Category`, e.g. `Groceries`, etc. With TensorFlow I have come so far:

```py
from __future__ import absolute_import, division, print_function, unicode_literals
import tensorflow as tf
import pandas as pd
URL = "transactions-0263445.csv"
dataframe = pd.read_csv(URL, sep=';')


# Build the keras Sequential model
model = Sequential()
model.add(...)
model.add(Activation(...))

# Train and evaluate the model
```

How do I build the [sequential model](https://keras.io/getting-started/sequential-model-guide/)? I am confused with specifying the input shape.

Comment: Add some input data such that we can see what we are working with. 
And i'm also tad confused regarding what you are looking for with this question.
Do you want to know how to process the data? Or which algorithm to use for the predictions?

Comment: @Mattias I have re-phrased my question and provided some input data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a classification problem, but there are some issues for me with your question, there are some steps that you need to take before dumping all the data into a model.

The thing is that I see no preprocessing of the data, are you using all features? Do they need to be scaled? Do you need to encode some data? there is a lot of things to look at before being able to create a model.

In this case, I am guessing that your main feature is the text? 
Here's a nice guide to how to do it: 
https://medium.com/data-from-the-trenches/text-classification-the-first-step-toward-nlp-mastery-f5f95d525d73

Or your own link:
https://medium.com/data-from-the-trenches/text-classification-the-first-step-toward-nlp-mastery-f5f95d525d73

Then you can build and train:
https://developers.google.com/machine-learning/guides/text-classification/step-4

Go through those thoroughly and you will be able to get what you are missing at the moment.